# ASP.NET MVC: have some issue With Custom Pagination

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've made my own Pagination,But i have some issue with it as you can see in page footer in Screen-shot i have **5** order in total , but it just show me **3** of them!! 
**And** when i click on page 1 or page 2 to see rest of order,but nothing going to showed up
**AND** when i in page 1,2 or 3 and then i hit back button on my browser to back to that page i was before ,but i cant because browser or... cant Remember wat page i was before,therefore i will back to that page as browser can Remember from last time index or wat ever i was. 
Can anyone direct me in the right direction?
thx

Comment: You have not shown us the `SearchOrderList()` script

Comment: @StephenMuecke i just update my question with script :)

Comment: Your using ajax, not redirecting so you will never have the browser back button work (unless you use `localStorage` or manipulate the browser history)

Comment: would you please , write the code or give me some example,it will be big help if you can wirte the code , i straggle with this about 3 days :(

Comment: Use a paging plugin such as PagedList (mentioned in Isma's answer) or at least study its source code (and it will work fine with your 'SearchAutoComplete' - but we cannot guess what you were doing wrong with that)

Comment: Need to see code, and the screenshot you mentioned might be helpful as well.